Get 6 month average of ACWP to forecast EA the next 6 months in power bi
I have a table called ProcessTable and it contains columns as shown below relationship model.
Below is the data model / relationship and dataset.

ProcessTable



Company
Reporting_Date
ProcessName
EA
ACWP
Planned




A
01/04/2023
Shredding
1668
1618
1868


B
01/04/2023
Cutting
600
550
800


C
01/04/2023
Painting
500
450
700


A
01/05/2023
Shredding
1800
1750
2000


B
01/05/2023
Cutting
700
650
900


C
01/05/2023
Painting
550
500
750


A
01/06/2023
Shredding
2000
1950
2200


B
01/06/2023
Cutting
800
750
1000


C
01/06/2023
Painting
590
540
790


A
01/07/2023
Shredding
2200
2150
2400


B
01/07/2023
Cutting
900
850
1100


C
01/07/2023
Painting
600
550
800


A
01/08/2023
Shredding
2400
2350
2600


B
01/08/2023
Cutting
1000
950
1200


C
01/08/2023
Painting
650
600
850


A
01/09/2023
Shredding
2600
2550
2800


B
01/09/2023
Cutting
1050
1000
1250


C
01/09/2023
Painting
700
650
900



DateTable  Note: My date table is a continuous date ( in days). I used StartofMonth rather than days to avoid typing.



Date
Period_MonthYear




01/04/2023
P1 Apr-23


01/05/2023
P2 May-23


01/06/2023
P3 Jun-23


01/07/2023
P4 Jul-23


01/08/2023
P5 Aug-23


01/09/2023
P6 Sep-23


01/10/2023
P7 Oct-23


01/11/2023
P8 Nov-23


01/12/2023
P9 Dec-23


01/01/2024
P10 Jan-24


01/02/2024
P11 Feb-24


01/03/2024
P12 Mar-24


01/04/2024
P1 Apr-24


01/05/2024
P2 May-24


01/06/2024
P3 Jun-24


01/07/2024
P4 Jul-24


01/08/2024
P5 Aug-24


01/09/2024
P6 Sep-24



CompayTable



Compay
Index




A
1


B
2


C
3



I want to achieve the Average of ACWP for the last 6 months, then divide the average by 6 which is 6 months and the add it to EA last period that is P6 Sep-23 and to forecast EA the next 6 months.
Below is an calculation
The Forecast EA is calculated as follow

get Average of 6 month ACWP for each ProcessName (i.e. Shredding, Cutting, Painting). The average of Shredding ACWP for the last 6 months and same applies to other ProcessName
divide Average ACWP  for each ProcessName by 6 (6months)
Forecast EA is calculated as : get the EA last date that is 01/09/2023

The chart below is what I want to achieve after the calculation


side note: date table requires continuous dates; in your current design, you won't be able to use time intelligence functions.

@RADO My date table is a continuous dates. I just put this as a table to avoid creating date records. Above date table is just to demo
